# What is the meaning of 片頬で笑う?

Tags: meaning, words

Does it describe that reserved sort of smile, when you slightly raise just one corner of your mouth?
Or a smirk?

Or is it an idiom that shouldn't be taken literally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

片頬 means "one cheek" (one of a pair (片) + cheek (頬) = one cheek (片頬)). So, 片頬で笑う would mean to smile with only one side of your face (which I assume is what you meant in the first sentence of your question).

I don't think this on its own is an idiom, but after research I did find one idiom that contains the phrase: [男は三年に片頬笑う](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/260503/meaning/m0u/). It describes a man who only smiles like this very rarely (i.e. "once every three years") because smiling too much will damage his dignity.

Comment: Ah, OK =) But does it convey any particular mood or emotion?

Comment: @Laliana Depends on context; probably nothing different from what you would expect.